# BubbleSort Application for vb.net unknown error

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub InsertionSort(ByRef intArray() As Integer)
    Dim intIndex, intPreviousIndex, intTempItem As Integer

    For intIndex = 1 To intArray.Length - 1
        intTempItem = intArray(intIndex)
        intPreviousIndex = intIndex - 1

        Do While intPreviousIndex > 0
        And intArray(intPreviousIndex) > intTempItem
            intArray(intPreviousIndex + 1) = intArray(intPreviousIndex)
            intPreviousIndex = intPreviousIndex - 1
        Loop

        If intArray(intPreviousIndex) > intTempItem Then
            intArray(intPreviousIndex + 1) = intArray(intPreviousIndex)
            intArray(intPreviousIndex) = intTempItem
        End If
    Next intIndex
End Sub
```

Why am i getting an error Where the "And" is?? The error is:

> Error 1   Syntax error.   H:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BubbleSort\BubbleSort\Form1.vb   48  13  BubbleSort

Does anyone know why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because implicit line continuation works AFTER `And`, not before it. You can either shift your `And` up one line, or add explicit line continuation (underscore <kbd>_</kbd>). So either this:

```
Do While intPreviousIndex > 0 And
intArray(intPreviousIndex) > intTempItem
```

Or this:

```
Do While intPreviousIndex > 0 _
And intArray(intPreviousIndex) > intTempItem
```

Should work. Official references:

- [Statements in Visual Basic (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/865x40k4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), look under **Continuing a Statement over Multiple Lines**.
- [Implicit Line Continuation in VB 10 (Tyler Whitney) @ blogs.msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/03/27/implicit-line-continuation-in-vb-10-tyler-whitney.aspx).